# Projective Varieties - Question 4.21 W. Fulton

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Problem** - Need to show that if two varieties satisfy $V\subset W \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ and $V$ is a hypersurface, then $W=V$ or $W=\mathbb{P}^n$.

**Observation** - The analog for affine varieties is valid. However, I am not able to take this case to the projective level. If you have another idea that gets the result, it will help a lot too.

Help me please! thanks.

Comment: You are assuming $V$ and $W$ to be irreducible, right? I did so in my answer because I think that is how 'variety' is defined in Fulton's book .

Comment: Exactly. Varieties are prejective algebraic sets that are irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $V$ to be the hypersurface determined by the irreducible form $f$ and $W$ the variety defined by a homogeneous prime ideal $I(W) =\frak{p}$. By the projective nullstellensatz, we see that the following inclusions hold. $$0 \subset \mathfrak{p} \subset(f)$$
Now, assume $W \neq \mathbb{P}^n$ and suppose $g \in \mathfrak{p}$ is a nonzero form of minimal degree. Then, $g \in (f)$ so we may write $g = g_0f$ for some other form $g_0$. Since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, we must have $g_0 \in \mathfrak{p}$ or $f \in \mathfrak{p}$. If $g_0 \in \mathfrak{p}$, however, this would contradict the minimality of the degree of $g$. Hence, $f \in \mathfrak{p}$, so that $\mathfrak{p} = (f)$. The projective nullstellensatz then implies $V = W$.

Comment: I found a great solution! However, there is something that is not very clear. Suppose that $f \in \mathfrak{p}$ not result in the same contradiction as when we suppose $g_0 \in \mathfrak{p}$? That is, wouldn't the same contradiction happen with the minimality of the degree of $g$?

Comment: It would not: If $\mathfrak{p} = (f)$ and $g \in \mathfrak{p}$ is of minimal degree, then we must have $g = g_0 f$ where $g_0$ is a form of degree 0, that is, $g_0 \in k$. In particular, the forms of minimal degree in $\mathfrak{p}$ are exactly the scalar multiples of $f$.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot for the help!